# What exactly is its return value of openAccessory?

Tags: java, android, usb, accessory

I'm struggling with resume of my Android App when connected to USB accessory.

Obviously my `ParcelFileDescriptor` is null, and the method `openAccessory()` doesn't return anything when I call it `onResume()`.

Anybody experienced that, yet?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be fixed, I had unread messages in the USB pipe.

The USB accessory did not read the sent messages from Android.

That's why the App couldn't get a new `ParcelFileDescriptor` from `onResume()`.

Comment: Please accept your own answer so that the question shows as having been resolved.